# Does anyone have an Avaya Telephony Services API (TSAPI) for C# sample application and tutorial?

Tags: c#, .net, telephony, avaya

I have found one from SourceForge and one from the Avaya site. The tutorial that Avaya providing is too advanced, so a beginner tutorial would be useful.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's TSASPI? Also elaborate a little more on what you want exactly.

Comment: @Mamta Dalal Uncle Google says it's the Texas State Association of Plumbing Inspectors, Inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest registering on Avaya DevConnect website: http://devconnect.avaya.com. You'll likely find more information there, including product documentation, tutorials and discussion board. Not sure they have tutorial for C# though, but it's worth to check.

@Mamta Dalal: TSAPI is one of the Computer Telephony Integration APIs used to control Avaya phone switches.

Comment: Website changed, it is now https://www.avaya.com/en/partners/devconnect/ or https://www.devconnectmarketplace.com/ it seems. But I can't say if it is the same information available.